# User registration validation using js. JS is not showing any errors, simply doesn't run

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to use simple JS to validate user password when registering, however page does not display any errors and runs as if the JS doesn't even exist (though it is added at the end of php file `<script src="script.js"></script>`). Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong are welcome, as I can't seem to figure it out. I am completely new to JS but need to do this for school, was trying to implement it in the simplest possible way.

Example of JS:

```
const name = document.getElementById('name')
const password = document.getElementById('password')
const form = document.getElementById('registerForm')
const errorElement = document.getElementById('error')
const button = document.getElementById('signUp')

if (button) {
    form.addEventListener(button, (e) => {
        let messages = []
        if (name.value === '' || name.value == null) {
            messages.push('Name is required.')
        }
        if (password.value.length <= 6) {
            messages.push('Password must be longer than 6 characters.')
        }
        if (password.value.length >= 20) {
            messages.push('Password must be less than 20 characters.')
        }
        if (messages.length > 0) {
            e.preventDefault()
            errorElement.innerText = messages.join(', ')
        }
    })
}
```

The snip from html:

```
<form id="registerForm" class="register" method="post">
          <div id = "signup_form" class="textboxes">
          <input id="name" type = "text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
          <input id="email" type = "email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
          <input id="password" type = "password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          <input id="repeat_password" type = "password" name="password_again" placeholder="Repeat password">
          <button id="signUp" type="submit" name="btn-register">Sign Up</button>
          <div id = "error"></div>
```

Comment: look at the addEventListener docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thanks, I did, makes it clearer. For now I have put the js code into a function and placed directly in the html, also added the oncklick in the button where I call the function and it finally started to work. Not the nicest solution, but it works and my assignment is completed. Next time, I will do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just missed a few things. The formatting of your HTML was not proper, and to add an event listener, you need to use the form `target.addEventListener(type, listener [, options]);`

Here, you want to have the "target" be the button since this is triggering the action. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for more info.

```js
const name = document.getElementById('name')
const password = document.getElementById('password')
const form = document.getElementById('registerForm')
const errorElement = document.getElementById('error')
const button = document.getElementById('signUp')

if (button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let messages = []
    if (name.value === '' || name.value == null) {
      messages.push('Name is required.')
    }
    if (password.value.length <= 6) {
      messages.push('Password must be longer than 6 characters.')
    }
    if (password.value.length >= 20) {
      messages.push('Password must be less than 20 characters.')
    }
    if (messages.length > 0) {
      e.preventDefault()
      errorElement.innerText = messages.join(', ')
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<form id="registerForm" class="register" method="post">
  <div id="signup_form" class="textboxes">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input id="repeat_password" type="password" name="password_again" placeholder="Repeat password" />
    <button id="signUp" type="submit" name="btn-register">Sign Up</button>
    <div id="error"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me a better understanding of event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

`form.addEventListener(button` doesn't make any sense. You have to tell `addEventListener` the name of an event to listen out for. In this case, the "submit" event of the form is the one you ought to be listening to.

Also the `if(button)` block didn't seem to have any useful purpose, so I removed that too, and the HTML snippet you provided was missing a couple of closing tags from the end.

Working demo:

```js
const name = document.getElementById('name')
const password = document.getElementById('password')
const form = document.getElementById('registerForm')
const errorElement = document.getElementById('error')
const button = document.getElementById('signUp')

  form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    let messages = []
    if (name.value === '' || name.value == null) {
      messages.push('Name is required.')
    }
    if (password.value.length <= 6) {
      messages.push('Password must be longer than 6 characters.')
    }
    if (password.value.length >= 20) {
      messages.push('Password must be less than 20 characters.')
    }
    if (messages.length > 0) {
      e.preventDefault()
      errorElement.innerText = messages.join(', ')
    }
  })
```

```html
<form id="registerForm" class="register" method="post">
  <div id="signup_form" class="textboxes">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input id="repeat_password" type="password" name="password_again" placeholder="Repeat password">
    <button id="signUp" type="submit" name="btn-register">Sign Up</button>
    <div id="error"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

P.S. It's also worth noting that the validation you've got here is very simple, and you could achieve the same results using [HTML5 validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation), just by adding attributes to your HTML form elements, and you wouldn't need to write any JavaScript at all:

```html
<form id="registerForm" class="register" method="post">
  <div id="signup_form" class="textboxes">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required minlength="6" maxlength="20">
    <input id="repeat_password" type="password" name="password_again" placeholder="Repeat password" required minlength="6" maxlength="20">
    <button id="signUp" type="submit" name="btn-register">Sign Up</button>
    <div id="error"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you as well! I wanted to avoid using the submit because we have multiple buttons on the same form and I thought it would clash. Unfortunately, I could not use the HTML5 Validations as it was specified in my assignment. Though I appreciate the suggestion and advice.